# How does mass affect the range of a nuclear particle?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, nuclear-physics, radiation

Heavy particles such as protons and alpha particles of certain energy will lose all their energies in a definite distance in a medium, and this distance is called the range. The range is the distance travelled by the particle.

The range depends on the energy and mass of the particles. The higher the energy, the larger is the range. When two particles have the same kinetic energy, the heavier one has a shorter range.

I am quite at ease with the concept that charged particle will tend to interact more with matter and therefore will have a shorter range than neutrally charged or less charged ones. But how do energy, momentum and mass relate to the range of a particle? Thanks!

Comment: have a look at my answer here http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/221870/electrons-muons-through-matter/221885#221885 and links therein

Comment: The Particle Data Group maintains a very thorough review on [the passage of particles through matter](http://pdg.lbl.gov/2015/reviews/rpp2014-rev-passage-particles-matter.pdf).